# How to create a function which can work on future elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume that i have a function that add a border to the element:

```
$.fn.border = function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
}
```

and i add to to my document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.elem').border();
});
```

This will work fine, but now if i need to add other elements to the dom via ajax, they won't get the border. Are there any way to delegate this to future elements?

something similar to this click event:

```
$('div').on('click', 'a', function() {
    // do something
})
```

Comment: Can't you do the whole job in your CSS? You shouldn't need JS.

Comment: `$('.elem').border();`  fires only once when DOM is ready...

Comment: couldn't you just call it after you add the elements?

Comment: @RRR - Correct. And the OP knows that already, hence the question of how to deal with future elements...

Comment: @nnnnnn - don't you think if i could do it i would? this is just a simple example. my real task is to assign some style to an image based on if it is portrait or landscape

Comment: @BenG - no i can't this would cause too much modification if i have to change something. i need to make it generic

Comment: do you always add the new elements the same? ie `.html`?

Answer (score 1):

you can run your code and create the border after each DOM modification

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
   $('.elem').border();
});
```

Comment: this is a working solution, but is it supported by all browsers?

Comment: for IE you can use intead of DOMSubtreeModified the propertychange event and for modern browser you can use MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a class to these elements through which they will automatically have this style.

```
(function createBorderClass()
{
   var style = document.createElement('style');
   style.type = 'text/css';
   style.innerHTML = '.elem{ border: 1px solid red; }'; 
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
})();
```

now you simply needs to ensure that elements you are creating from AJAX response has this class.

you can make it more dynamic by doing

```
(function createBorderClass(selector, prop, value)
{
   var style = document.createElement('style');
   style.type = 'text/css';
   style.innerHTML = selector+ '{ ' + prop + ': ' + value + ' }'; 
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
})(".elem", "border", "1px solid red");
```

Comment: that's the problem... i cannot do it via css.  This was just a simple example. i should do it only in js as i cannot add or remove class to the element. so i will not know what class the element has.

Comment: @user2707590 it is a js solution only. you can add a style via js also.

Comment: i need to do it for future elements that are added to dom.

Comment: @user2707590  since the future elements already have the classname, this style will apply to them

Comment: *"i will not know what class the element has"* - then how do you distinguish the element from other elements that might be added?